# Help identify the country and the invention of this patent 20877

Tags: identifying

[image]

This plate for patent number 20877, dated November 16, 1921, is on a horse-racing slot machine.  What does this patent cover and where was it issued?

Based on the date (November 16, 1921), it's not a United States utility or design patent.  US utility patent 20877 and design patent 20877 were both issued several decades earlier.  Also, I don't believe slot machines were patentable in the US at that time, since they weren't considered "useful" - however it's possible that the slot machine contained a patented device used in other non-gaming devices.

Edit:  I've checked the USTPO, Google Patents, and Espacenet.  Nothing matches both the date and patent number.

Comment: I looked on Google Patents and The Lens and didn't find anything that matched either

Comment: Yeah, I checked Google patents and the USPTO.

Comment: I wonder if it isn’t a “pattern” number used only by the manufacturer.

Comment: If "Pat" is for "Pattern", then the date could be a manufacture date.  If we can establish that the device was manufactured at or around that date, then "Pattern" makes sense.

Comment: It's all speculation from me. It the item a potential collectable?

Comment: Yes, and there's a good chance that some collectors' books have details on the manufacture dates and use dates. I am trying to track this down for a friend of mine.  I will ask him what historical material there is on it.

Comment: Are there manufacturer marks other than this plaque? That could cut down the origin

Comment: There isn’t anything identifying the manufacturer.  There is a book for collectors that identifies all the old slot machines and what is known about them.  All it says for this one is “manufacturer unknown”.  That’s why we’re trying to see if the (assumed) patent number could tell us something about it.